# MySQL CSV (involving timestamps) Import through Workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, format, timestamp, workbench

I am trying to import a CSV with columns [ID, timestamp, account, liters]->[#, datetime, #, #] using the MYSQL workbench  6.3. MySQL creates the table fine using the CSV (imports 1 record) and then I reimport the same CSV for data rows. MySQL identifies the columns and matches them with table well. Then it takes a long time and reports that all rows have been imported but table shows no rows.

I have searched forums and seem people had problems with timestamps but the solutions involved using the commandline. Can someone please guide if I should format my csv differently? It's a big pain. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the import command you used, along with the _first_ line from the input file (containing the headers), and the _second_ line (i.e. the first line of data)?

Answer (score 0):

OK..so this was problem with date format. When I specified the datetime field, I couldn't see a field popping up at the bottom to specify the format as per https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior (screen resolution issues). Anyway, I types in the matching format there and CSV is importing now..Thanks